# Apple compatibility Issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I have a macbook air 2014, with the operation system sierra. I have been advised not to update it by apple, as the higher OS might not be compatible with the HW of the device . I want to develop ios apps.
So I have downloaded flutter 1.22, and x-code 9.2(higher versions are not compatible with the current MAc os )
but flutter requires minimum version of 11 for x-code
I thought of downloading an older version of flutter that would be compatible with the existing x-code
but then somewhere i read apple store won't support any ios app that is been render from an x-code below the version 11,
seriously! is that correct ?
and if so, what shall I do now with these compatibles issues, any suggestion would be appreciated !

Comment: This is not an issue. If you want to develop iOS specific applications then you need the latest updates and softwares. Apple is very strict concerning the version targeted to develop an app. Flutter simply adapted to the new policy.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.apple.com/macos/big-sur-preview/) you can see even latest unreleased macOS Big Sur is supported by devices until Macbook Air 2013.

I don't know who or how they told you to not to update your operating system because this is quite opposite of what Apple suggest in general.

Comment: By not updating the OS for so long OP might need to first update to High Sierra because his machine might require a firmware update to be compatible with Mojave, Catalina and Big Sur.